# asp net mvc partial view validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, partial-views

Hi how are you? I'm trying to validate a form in ASP NET MVC.

I have a partial view "Address" that I reuse for some entities, like Company, Person, etc.

My problem is that when I submit the form, only the controls of the father view gets validated, the ones in the partial view don't.

Here's some code I hope u can geive me hand

**PERSON VIEW**

```
@model Entities.Person


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                <div class="control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @maxlength = 7, @class = "numeric"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="spacer-short"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                <div class="control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @maxlength = 7, @class = "numeric"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                </div>
                <div class="spacer-short"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Address", new {id = Model.AddressId});} //Renders the Address form part

    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <button type="submit" data-button="true" data-button-icon="ui-icon-disk" class="">Create</button>
    <button type="button" data-button="true" data-button-icon="ui-icon-circle-close" class="button-cancel">Cancel</button>
}
```

**ADDRESS VIEW**

```
@model Entities.Address


<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street)
            <div class="control">
                @Html.TextBox("Address.Street", Model.Street)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Address.Street")
             </div>
           <div class="spacer-short"></div>
           </td>
           <td>
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
              <div class="control">
                @Html.TextBox("Address.Number", Model.Number)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Address.Number")
             </div>
           <div class="spacer-short"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then I have some validation metadata ([Required]) for person and address fields

Comment: Have you tried replacing @{Html.RenderAction...} with @Html.Partial("Address")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Street)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.Street)
```

instead of this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Address.Street", Model.Street)
@Html.ValidationMessage("Address.Street")
```

Answer (score 8):

A common mistake using `@Html.Partial(...)` and expecting validation errors to show up is not passing ViewData to that partial.:

```
@Html.Partial([ViewName], [EmailAddressObject], ViewData)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. The catch is that when you only call partial with two first argument (viewname and usually model) it works fine (so I guess ViewData gets passed implicitly). But if you pass something custom (for example a flag to change output of the partial) and don't attach existing ViewData, you will lose some information. In my case the input-validation-error class wasn't applied to the inputs with validation error contained in partial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Html.Partial(...)` instead of `Html.RenderAction(...)` to render the partial view. This may be suppressing the validations.

Comment: I've tried Html.RenderPartial before using RenderAction with the same results. That would be the same as Html.Partial doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

> İmportant: Manage Nuget Packages

=>> JQuery.Validation

=>> Microsoft.JQueryUnobtrusive.Validation

install.

**1) First step**

> using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

**2)**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Kategori adı boş geçilemez.")]
    [DisplayName("Kategori Adı")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Kategori açıklaması boş geçilemez.")]
    [DisplayName("Kategori Açıklaması")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

**3)**

```
if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var categoryCreate = new Categories
                    {
                       //code
                    };
                    _CategoriesService.Create(categoryCreate);
                }
```

**4)** 
Add ViewModel
@model Models.CategoryViewModel
After

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "categoryTitle", @placeholder = "Kategori adını giriniz.", @type= "text", @required=true })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "error-message" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "categoryArticle", @placeholder = "Kategori açıklamasını giriniz.", @type = "text", @required = true })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "error-message" })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once I put that in my _layout.cshtml file, it started working even with partial views.